# Spring boot - Spark Application: Unable to process a file on its nodes

Tags: apache-spark, spring-boot, batch-processing

> I have the below setup:
>
> Spark Master and Slaves configured and running in my local.

```
17/11/01 18:03:52 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkMaster' on port 7077.
17/11/01 18:03:52 INFO Master: Starting Spark master at spark://127.0.0.1:7077

17/11/01 18:03:52 INFO Master: Running Spark version 2.2.0
17/11/01 18:03:52 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'MasterUI' on port 8080.
```

> I have a spring boot application whose properties file contents look like the below:

spark.home=/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.2.0/bin/
master.uri=spark://127.0.0.1:7077

```
@Autowired
    SparkConf sparkConf;

    public void processFile(String inputFile, String outputFile) {
        JavaSparkContext javaSparkContext;
        SparkContext sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf);
        SerializationWrapper sw= new SerializationWrapper() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public JavaSparkContext createJavaSparkContext() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return JavaSparkContext.fromSparkContext(sc);
            }
        };
        javaSparkContext=sw.createJavaSparkContext();

        JavaRDD<String> lines = javaSparkContext.textFile(inputFile);
        Broadcast<JavaRDD<String>> outputLines;
        outputLines = javaSparkContext.broadcast(lines.map(new Function<String, String>() {

            /**
             * 
             */
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public String call(String arg0) throws Exception {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return arg0;
            }
        }));

        outputLines.getValue().saveAsTextFile(outputFile);
        //javaSparkContext.close();
    }
```

When i run the code I'm getting the below error:

```
17/11/01 18:16:36 INFO TorrentBroadcast: Started reading broadcast variable 2
17/11/01 18:16:36 INFO TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to /192.168.0.135:51903 after 1 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
17/11/01 18:16:36 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_2_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 24.4 KB, free 366.3 MB)
17/11/01 18:16:36 INFO TorrentBroadcast: Reading broadcast variable 2 took 82 ms
17/11/01 18:16:36 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_2 stored as values in memory (estimated size 67.2 KB, free 366.2 MB)
17/11/01 18:16:36 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1)
java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy to field org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$dependencies_ of type scala.collection.Seq in instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2133)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1305)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2251)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2245)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
17/11/01 18:16:36 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
```

> The springboot-spark app should process the files based on REST API call where i get the input and output file location shared across the Spark nodes.
>
> Any suggestions to fix the above errors

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not broadcast a JavaRDD, since a RDD is already distributed among your cluster nodes.

Comment: I tried without broadcaster as well, it didnt worked :-(, got the same error.

Comment: It might be an environment problem then. [This](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19938) may help you.